# Approaching multiple optimization problems

Tags: optimization, hidden-markov-models

I am currently looking at solving an optimization problem of the form

$min\ f(arg\max\limits_{k}\quad\max\limits_{\theta} g(k,\theta,t))$

I would really appreciate some guidance in algorithms to solve such problems. The function g is the viterbi state sequence $g(\theta) = p(\text{state seq}=\theta | observation)$

The function f is a mapping from state sequences such that

$f = \sum_{k=0}^{k=\frac{T}{100}}\sum_{t=100k}^{t=100k+100} I(state_t \neq state_{t-1})$

This should in essence minimize the number of state transitions in the most likely sequence.

Comment: Do you mean to have argmax alongside max?

Comment: I think that is what a viterbi decoding does. It finds the most likely state at time t while maximizing the sequence upto t-1. This is done in a recursive way by treating it as time series and using the markov assumption. I am not sure if there is a general way to state that problem, but feel free to edit the question.

Comment: The notation doesn't make sense as written because $\max_\theta g(\theta)$ is merely a scalar, not a function. What variable is the argmax taken with respect to? What variable is the argmin taken with respect to?

Comment: $\max_\theta g(k,\theta)$ is a function of $k$; you take the arg max of that over $k$ and you get a single number (or vector or whatever, one point in "phase space"). How can you then minimize that?

Comment: Sorry about that. I have some trouble framing the problem mathematically. The data is a time series, so I get a k at every time. F tries to map that sequence to a scalar and I am trying to minimize that.